# loop to run two way frequency table r

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have data such as this:

```
dat <- mtcars %>% mutate(cyl2 = cyl*2,cyl3 = cyl*3)
```

I want to generate frequency tables such as this:

```
table(dat$cyl, dat$vs)
table(dat$cyl2, dat$vs)
table(dat$cyl3, dat$vs)
table(dat$cyl, dat$am)
table(dat$cyl2, dat$am)
table(dat$cyl3, dat$am)
```

Is there a way to automate the generation of frequency tables so that I don't have to run it each time like I have in the example above. First, the actual data I have is a lot bigger and second, the output isn't very easy to digest.

Now, if I wanted only the frequency of each variable, I could do something like so:

```
mapply(table, dat); mylist
```

**There must be a way to run apply for a two way frequency distribution?? Thank you for your insight.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to put all of the tables you want into a list:

```
vars <- as.matrix(expand.grid(c("cyl", "cyl2", "cyl3"), c("vs", "am")))
tables <- lapply(seq(nrow(vars)), function(x) table(dat[, vars[x, ]]))
lbls <- apply(vars, 1, paste, collapse="_")
names(tables) <- lbls
```

You can access a table if you know the number (row number in `vars`) or the combination of factors, e.g.

```
tables[[3]]
#     vs
# cyl3  0  1
#   12  1 10
#   18  3  4
#   24 14  0
tables[["cyl3_vs"]]
#     vs
# cyl3  0  1
#   12  1 10
#   18  3  4
#   24 14  0
```